# Java static class for application meta info to populate JLabels in NetBeans

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, jlabel

In my application, I have a "meta" class to store information about the app (e.g., version).

For example:

```
class AppMetaData {
  public static final String version = "beta2";
  public static final String server = ...
  ...
}
```

In NetBeans, I have a JLabel on the main frame of my application. I want it's value to be populated from this MetaClass. However the code is auto-generated for it and I see no way to set it's value dynamically from the version field of the MetaData class. It is either set by hand, or drawn from some text file.

Is there a simple way to achieve what I want, in a way that it won't be overwritten by the code generator?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JLabel` has a `setText` method that you should call in a place that you know for sure that won't be overridden by the IDE.

Comment: I don't see a reason why it is not an elegant solution. I think that most of the Swing developers don't use UI designers and they either set the label text in the constructor or using the setText method.